# Redirect process doesn't work in php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication

I made a login form but the redirect doesn't work.

```
 $sql = "SELECT * from login where username = '$username' and password = '$password'";
 $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysql_error()) ;
 $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
  if ($rows == 1 ) {
        header('Location: home.php');
    } else {
        echo "Failed";
    }
    echo "hello";
    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't a good description. Update your question with what happens instead of "doesn't work".

Comment: What happens? Any error message? Do you have display_errors turned on? Do you have any output before your `header()`? A note as well, you should use Prepared Statements and you should use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` when dealing with user passwords. You should also have an `exit;` after the header-call to stop the execution of the file. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not complete.
Please update in more detail.

Also, instead of the header code, you can display a text to better identify.

---

If your problem is the header code, this is basically the reason:

Check the blank space at the beginning of your document.

Example :

```
space space space line


<b>     <?php
header('Location: panel.php');
 ?>
</b>
```

It's likely that this code will not work.

so change to :

```
<?php
//First check for redirect..
if( 1 == 1)// or any clause [optional]
{
    header('Location: panel.php');
}
?>
    <b>    <?php echo 5*25; ?>
</b>
```

---

Also, to ensure you can also write this code (after `header("Location: ...");`).

```
exit('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=link.php" />');
```

- `0` is time (s).
- `link.php` is target/link.

Comment: Don't post comments as answers. You said it your self, _"Your question is not complete"_ and therefor, any answer wouldn't be either. If you don't have enough rep to comment, work on that first. Answers are reserved for actual _solutions_. Commenting is a privilege and trying to bypass the rep restrictions like this is _not_ a good way to earn rep, rather the opposite.

Comment: OK.
But I just wanted to help. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: @MagnusEriksson , it line is a example condition , like check database or any!

Comment: I understand and you should keep at it. Just pointing out answers should contain solutions to the actual issue. If the OP hasn't written a good question containing all the info, you can't really write a proper solution and the OP needs to amend the question first. Basically, if you need to ask the OP for something, it should be a comment.

Comment: Ok. It got a bit confusing. When I read your answer, it actually looks like you're saying that the redirect needs to be inside an if-condition. Tip: try and keep answers as minimal as possible (except from the explanations, that is).